# dependencies for a library jar using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-dependencies, gradle6.7

I am using gradle 6.7 and creating a library project which is compiled to a jar that is placed in my own s3 artifacts repository.

In my project I have dependencies to other artifacts and I use *implementation* dependency.

The jar is created (not a fat jar) and uploaded to the s3 repository.

When in another project I am using my library by fetching it as *implementation dependency* I am getting errors NoClassDef for other dependencies I used in my library, which means that no runtime is found for the dependencies I was using in my library.

My question is, whether it is a good idea to create a fat jar? I don't think that other libraries (e.g. springboot and others) are using fat jars, right? however when I use them as dependency other dependencies are found on runtime.

Does it mean that using *implementation* in my project for other dependencies is not the right way? shall I use something else? Could you please contribute a bit more about what is the right way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Java Library Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) for gradle. It exists for this exact situation.

If a dependency of your library needs to be exposed to the consumer of your library, then you would use `api` instead of `implementation`. There is a nice section within the plugin documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_recognizing_dependencies) that can be used to help you identify when to declare a dependency as `api` vs `implementation`.